# gaussian upper bound on spherical heat kernel

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis

It is known that the heat kernel on n-sphere satisfies $p_t(x,y)\leq Ct^{-n/2}e^{-d(x,y)^2/5t}$ for all $t\in (0,T)$. Can something be said about how big C needs to be?

Comment: A remark: the constant $5$ in the exponent is not optimal; a two-sided bound with optimal constant $4$ in the exponent has been proved recently by [Nowak, Sjögren and Szarek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09385). Of course the constant $C$ depends on $T$, and it is not given explicitly in the cited article. Perhaps it could found by following the proof carefully. Out of curiosity: why do you care about the exact value of this constant?